# How can I check a string for multiple certain characters?

Tags: php, regex, string, character

I have a string and I need to check it for several characters. I can do that with `strpos();`. But in this case, I would need to use `strpose();` several times. something like this:

```
$str = 'this is a test';
if(
   strpos($str, "-") === false &&
   strpos($str, "_") === false &&
   strpos($str, "@") === false &&
   strpos($str, "/") === false &&
   strpos($str, "'") === false &&
   strpos($str, "]") === false &&
   strpos($str, "[") === false &&
   strpos($str, "#") === false &&
   strpos($str, "&") === false &&
   strpos($str, "*") === false &&
   strpos($str, "^") === false &&
   strpos($str, "!") === false &&
   strpos($str, "?") === false &&
   strpos($str, "{") === false &&
   strpos($str, "}") === false 
  )
    { do stuff }
```

Now I want to know, is it possible to use a `regex` to define my condition summary?

---

**Edit:** here is some examples:

```
$str = 'foo'     ----I want this output---> true
$str = 'foo!'    -------------------------> false
$str = '}foo'    -------------------------> false
$str = 'foo*bar' -------------------------> false
```

and so on. In other word, I want just text character: `abcdefghi...` .

Comment: Please explain in literal form. Because I'm from non-php side don't know what the above code does.

Comment: @AvinashRaj check out my update ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative lookahead assertion.

```
if (preg_match("~^(?!.*?[-_^?}{\]\[/'@*&#])~", $str) ){
// do stuff
}
```

This will do the stuff inside braces only if the string won't contain anyone of the mentioned characters.

If you want the string to contain only word chars and spaces.

```
if (preg_match("~^[\w\h]+$~", $str)){
// do stuff
}
```

or

AS @Reizer metioned,

```
if(preg_match("~^[^_@/'\]\[#&*^!?}{-]*$~", $str)){
```

Replace the `*` (*present next to the character class*) in the above with `+`, if you don't want to match an empty string.

For only alphabets and spaces.

```
if(preg_match("~^[a-z\h]+$~i", $str) ){
```

Comment: Isn't a character class enough, e.g. `[^CharacersWhichYouDon'tWant]*` ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: ya, is there any `if !preg_match("~[-_^?}{\]\[/'@*&#]~", $str) {`

Comment: @Rizier123  could you explain me what op wants?

Comment: well, thanks, just do you think, for a *name* input (e.g. Raj), which one of the above codes in more appropriate ?

Comment: if the string contains only alphabets and spaces, you may use `if(preg_match("~^[a-z\h]+$~i", $str) ){`

Comment: sorry for asking again, just is it possible to I use of 2 variable in 1 `preg_match()` ? in fact I want to checks this phrase `~^[a-z\h]+$~i` for `$str1` and `$str2`

Answer (score 4):

You could use a basic regex:

```
$unwantedChars = ['a', '{', '}'];
$testString = '{a}sdf';

if(preg_match('/[' . preg_quote(implode(',', $unwantedChars)) . ']+/', $testString)) {
    print "Contains invalid characters!";
} else {
    print "OK";
}
```

Comment: This away give me a "invalid characters"....i'm tring to use words instead of characters

Answer (score 2):

May be something like that:

```
function strpos_multi(array $chars, $str) {
  foreach($chars as $char) {
    if (strpos($str, $char) !== false) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

$res = strpos_multi(["-", "_", "@", "/", "'", "]", "[", "#", "&", "*", "^", "!", "?", "{", "}"], $str);
if ($res) {
  //do some stuff
}
```